# Make hangs when attempting to build zip code TopJSON file on Mac OS X

Tags: geojson, merge

Thanks so much to all involved with the us-atlas project. I am learning how to use d3, leaflet and other tools to make maps and this is really helpful.

I have grabbed files from the us-atlas project on github (https://github.com/mbostock/us-atlas) and have had success doing the basic make for US Counties.

However, the make for US Zip codes seems to hang. I have tried running in background with & and also using nice to increase the priority but it still seems not to finish.

In response to Brad's question, the process has run in background for upwards of 10-11 hours overnight. The top command line utility at that point shows that node has 0% of CPU (whereas at the start I monitor and see it is taking 100% of CPU for the first hour).

Could it just be that the OS falls into sleep mode and it kills the processing?

Is there anything I can do to get OS X to keep the make (and subsequent node process) a priority and keep it going?

How long should this take with a 2.6GHz Intel Core i7 and 8MB RAM?

As an alternative I am mostly interested in MD Zip codes. Is there a way to restrict a TopoJSON build to just those zip codes?

Comment: Welcome to gis.SE. Do you mean this specific version: https://github.com/mbostock/us-atlas? How long are you running it for? You can update your question by clicking edit below the question.

Answer (score 1):

The makefile has a STATES variable, at line 6, that is set to 51 states. You should be able to edit the file, removing all states except MD. Then you can run make.

Comment: Thanks, klewis, that was definitely worth a try. Process still seems to hang and die out. Been running about 5 hours now and although it created the shell topos/us-zipcodes.json file, it remains empty.

Any thoughts on why this fails to complete or how to get it to persist and finish?